# UIScrollView on UIWebView and UITapGestureRecognizer conflicts

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uiscrollview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have a `UITapGestureRecognizer` on a `UIViewController`, which has a `UIScrollView` and `UIWebView` inside. It recognizes the tap gesture only after I scroll the `UIWebView`. How could I prevent this ?. Basically I want the tap gesture to be detected, when I am not scrolling the web view. I looked around and the closest I found is this:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer*)otherGestureRecognizer {
      return YES;
}
```

but not sure how can I use this to disable the tap while scrolling. Any idea?

Another thing I want to do is to disable the UITapGestureRecognizer, when a link on the UIWebView is clicked (shouldStartLoadWebRequest is called). I checked that the tap gesture recognizer is called, before the shouldStartLoadWebRequest is called. Basically when clicking on a link on a UIWebView, it shouldn't trigger the action invoked by the UITapGestureRecongnizer. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your view structure: is your web view *inside* your scroll view? Or are they next to one another?

Comment: Yes the web view is inside the scroll view. So it's UIViewController's view > UIScrollView which has a lot of UIWebView that can be scrolled horizontally.

Comment: @xonegirlz Have you solved this? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

So Apple's documentation [strongly recommends](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you don't nest a `UIWebView` inside a scroll view:

> Important: You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

It is possible on iOS 5 and above to get direct access to the underlying scroll view on a `UIWebView` (using the `scrollView`) property - playing around with this *might* help you.

Comment: I did not nest it directly inside a UIScrollView. I have a UIViewController then inside that is the UIWebView and yes, I was able to get the UIWebView scrollView, but that did not help. I am looking for some of your idea, "play with the UIWebView scroll view" as I tried a bunch of stuff and it didn't work